# Is the time complexity of the code snippet less than O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, array-algorithms

I am new to algorithms and data structures.
Thus, I joined LeetCode to improve my skills.
The first problem is to propose an algorithm whose time complexity is less than O(n^2).
I used the code snippet below.
The solution was accepted.

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int)->List[int]:
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        for y in range(x+1, len(nums)):
            if nums[x] + nums[y] == target:
                return [x, y]
    return [0, 0]

nums = [1,2,3,4]
target = 7
twoSum(nums, target)
```

But in worst case it iterates N items (indices -> [0,1,2,3]) by (N-1)/2  times (outer index: inner indices -> 0:[1,2,3], 1:[2,3], 2:[3]), seems like O(n^2).
Is there any mistake in in my reasoning?
Or there is an error on LeetCode?

Comment: That is not a function. If it was a function, eg `def myFunction(nums):`, it would be O(n^2)

Comment: It was a function. I edited the code to make it clear.

Comment: I don't know why it was accepted

Comment: LeetCode, nor any other algorithm exercise site, can really measure the time complexity of your code - they can only make a best guess based on its actual measured running time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is of O(n^2). You can easily calculate the time complexity of your solution which is basically the brute-force way of doing this problem.

In the worst case, you have a Sum of [n, n-1,..., 1] which is equal to n * (n + 1) /2 which is of O(n^2).

Note that such platforms cannot really calculate the time complexity, they just set a time limit on their system which is not accurate in any way.

There exists a simple solution for this problem using Hashmap which gives you a solution of O(n), hope you can figure it out yourself.